# how to make changes in .user.ini file on cpanel?

Tags: php, cpanel

My project directory has php.ini file on root and I want to make some changes to configuration therefore I edited php.ini file through cpanel but whenever I edit php.ini file a file .user.ini is created which has some directives already added. .user.ini file is being used by 'u' folder of my project which is on root. I tried editing .user.ini file through cpanel but changes do not reflect.

In snapshot you can see that changes done in php.ini which is on root has reflected changes but when I go inside 'u' folder of my project which is using .user.ini file the configurations are still disabled

[image: .user.ini configurations not reflecting within 'u' folder of project]

This is the extension I want to enable:

**allow_url_fopen**

If someone knows how I can make changes to .user.ini file please guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using MultiPHP from your cPanel web interface in order to change PHP settings.